# WCF service always returns random numbers in the response body

Tags: java, c#, rest, wcf

I have a WCF Service written in C#:

```
namespace MyServices
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IMyService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/foo/{param}")]
        string foo(string param);
    }
}

public class MyService : IMyService
{
    public string foo(string param)
    {
        //Do stuff with param
        return "Some processed data";
    }
}
```

Whenever I consume this service it works fine except for the fact that each line in the response is always preceded by a number(sometimes a number with a character). And the last line is always a 0.

Below is a client that consumes this service written in Java:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try 
        {
            Socket soc = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("<SOME IP ADDRESS>"), 80);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(soc.getOutputStream());
            String headers = "GET /MyService.svc/foo/some_data HTTP/1.1\r\n"
                             + "Host: <SOME HOST>\r\n"
                             + "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8\r\n"
                             + "Content-Length: 0\r\n\r\n";

            out.print(headers);
            out.flush();

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(soc.getInputStream()));
            String response;

            while((response = in.readLine())!=null)
            {
                //Do something with the response            
                System.out.println(response);
            }
            out.close();
            soc.close();
        catch (UnknownHostException e) 
        {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This would output the following:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Set-Cookie: ARRAffinity=2e5dd814a4cb78f8a5825d56c5879cd18fa384d20597b10f3c685ffe2cff1f53;Path=/;Domain=<SOME DOMAIN NAME>
Date: Tue, 02 Aug 2016 22:53:25 GMT

15
"Some processed data"
0
```

At first I thought the numbers represented the number of characters in the following line and the 0 indicated the end of the message body but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Any help is appreciated, Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the Transfer-Encoding is chunked (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding).
The 15 is in HEX meaning 21 characters in this chunk, with the 0 as closing marker.

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense now, I will just add functionality to handle Transfer- Encoding. Thanks

Comment: Why aren't you using a Java.net.HttpURLConnection instead ? It will handle these nitty gritty things like encoder modes and connections for you.

Comment: Yeah I ended up using that instead.